# How to start page numberring from a specific number in Birt?

Tags: birt

i'm trying to make my Birt repport page numberring to start from a specific number, so the first page number will be for example 30 , the second will be 31..., so i tried to add a constant to the pagenumber variable but it seems like i'm not doing it right

i'm using 'Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.6.0.v201606072122'

any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance